# How to declare 2D array outside of main of size 100001x100001 in C++?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to declare a 2D array of size 100001x100001 outside of the main function, but I'm getting "Size of array is too large".
How can I do it ?
my code

```
bool connected[100001][100001];

main()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can your system address 9GB of memory?

Comment: @vsoftco it is not possible/likely to have stack with that size

Comment: @BryanChen true, I computed the size first as 0.1Gb instead of 10Gb :) Removed the comment.

Comment: If a row can be compressed, i.e. 8 bits per byte, I get 1,250,012,500 bytes.  So there are 100001 rows of 12,500 bytes.  It looks possible on a platform that has 2 GB free memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to compress this matrix by using `uint8_t` instead of bool.

Let's assume there are 8 bools per uint8_t. 
100001 / 8 = 12,500
So in each row, there are 12,500 columns.

The declaration would be:

```
  uint8_t connections[100001][100001/8];
```

Most programming environments won't allow you to declare a huge array in global area.  You may have to tweak default settings to do this.

Another alternative is to use dynamic allocation:

```
int main(void)
{
  const unsigned int allocation_size = 100001 * (100001 / 8);
  uint8_t * connections = new uint8_t [allocation_size];
  // ...
  delete[] connections;
  return 0;
}
```

You would have to use *bit twiddling* to access the appropriate column.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I solved the problem by using vector . I used vector<int> v[100001] and it worked

Comment: Are you sure you want a vector of `int`?  An `int` on most systems is greater than 8 bits.  Let's assume `sizeof(int)` is 32 bits on your machine (4 bytes).  You are allocating 100001 * 4 bytes.  Is this enough bits (or bytes)?  By the way, you should be using **unsigned int** when playing with bits.  Most platforms reserve 1 bit to indicate whether the integer is signed or not.  So you are losing 100001 bits by using signed integers.

Comment: actually I was using the 2D array as a connectivity matrix to solve a graph based problem. So, I changed from adjacency matrix to adjacency lists expressed in vectors of int :)